# Google SignIn in app without adding it in device accounts

Tags: android, android-webview, google-oauth, google-signin, chrome-custom-tabs

We’ve been using Google SignIn through WebView, but as Google will be deprecating this soon, are there any alternatives to do the same ?

We have a slightly special use-case where our devices are being used in a warehouse and one device is being used by multiple users. We do not want all the users to add their accounts to every device. It seems like a fairly reasonable use-case but I can’t seem to find a official documentation for cases like this. Is there any work around to this?

Update:
Here is the use case in little more detail. Imagine 100 devices for 500 employees. None of the users have a dedicated device for them. Every morning they walk in and are issued a random device for next few hours. They need to then login into our preinstalled app through G Suite SSO, finish their work, and return devices after logging out.

Now, we do this SSO over webview because we don't want each of our workers to be setting up a google account to a device each and every day. With the new system, we don't have an alternative but to ask low skilled workers to setup complete device including sync options and what not.

We still want to use Google SSO coming from our G Suite accounts but don't want the accounts to be linked to the device itself.

Comment: Have the same issue here.

Comment: Are you using a custom tab instead of a webview now?

Comment: No, we ended up creating our own login screen. Google login using chrome custom tab takes through the same flow of account addition to the device.

Comment: Can we hear anything more about your solution?

Comment: Maybe could you try with Firebase Authentication, using Google Account?