# Is there a way to use Google Sign In without adding the account to the device?

Tags: java, android, google-signin

I'm making an app that needs the user to authenticate with Google, but it has to be done using email/password and the logged in account must not be added to the device account list.

Login is an easy thing to do with [Google SignIn](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/sign-in) but it doesn't meet my requirements.

I've searched similar questions but it seems there was no solution at the time, 
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42803258/google-signin-in-app-without-adding-it-in-device-accounts) and
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33196147/login-to-google-drive-on-android-without-adding-the-google-account-to-the-device)

Maybe now with the new versions of GoogleSignInClient or something similar is there a way to achieve this?
I just need to check email and password are correct.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

you can create an account without adding the account in your device you have to create 2 edit text and just enter that email-id and password on these fileds and pass in a method just like that:-

```
FirebaseAuth mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
createAccount(registerEmail.getText().toString(), registerPassword.getText().toString());
```

and create a method:-

```
private void createAccount(String email, String password) {
        mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        pd.dismiss();
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                          Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You are registered successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, task.getException().getMessage(),
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
    }
```